# How do I pass parameter from javascript into php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Javascript function which pass parameter into a php function. My javascript code is below

```
function add_card(card_listt,card_number){  
   var card = card_listt;
   var num = card_number;
   //document.write(card+num);
   for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      var avrl = "http://192.168.27.123/?Command=add:"+card[i]+","; 
      document.write('<?php get_data($avrl); ?>'); // Here is Problem
      document.write('<?php add(1,2); ?>'); //It works fine If I use  
   }
}
```

my php function is below. when I use only `document.write('<?php add(1,2);?>');` function then it works properly. But when I use `document.write('<?php get_data($avrl); ?>');` function then it does not works.

```
<?php

    function get_data($url) {
       $curl_handle=curl_init();
       $timeout = 20;
       curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
       curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
       curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Welcome');
       $data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
       //return $data;
       echo $data;
   }

   function add($a,$b){
      $c = $a + $b;
      echo $c;
   }

?>
```

Comment: @M Sumon You cannot call a php function like that. `avrl` is a javascript variable not a php variable.

Comment: Read about **AJAX**!

Comment: document.write('<?php add(1,2); ?>'); it works fine. But it's above not working.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php

Comment: @MSumon `document.write('<?php add(1,2); ?>');` this works fine because the values are static. You cannot pass a variable from javascript to PHP. Javascript is client side and PHP is server side. Use ajax to send data to server side.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET` append your value to the url like `http://www.example.com/someurl?myvar=myvalue` in this case your url should be `http://www.example.com/someurl?avrl=myvalue`.

Then replace your `document.write('<?php get_data($avrl); ?>');` with `document.write('<?php get_data($_GET['avrl']); ?>');`

Answer (score -1):

Try read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xmL/ajax_intro.asp) or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/), but i strongly recommend you to begin use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can do such things with it not wasting time writing huge amount of code, for example [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)